# Formula to automatically change expired dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to have a formula to change a date in **cell 1** when the date in cell 2 has expired?

Comment: you should be able to do this with a : if (cell2>expiration_date, ... , ...)

Comment: Thank you. I searched the net & could not find any reference .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
=IF(A2>B1;"TO_BE_CHANGED";A2)
```

### case 1- date  Ok

[image: case 1- date Ok]

### case 2 - date expired

[image: case 2 - to be changed]

Comment: Thank you both answers were extremely helpful.